# Typo3 tx_news extension with cs_seo extension show titleTag in Detail view

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I think this a common problem with no easy solution. Did anybody manage to show the News Title as page.titleTag in tx_news when using ce_seo?

Comment: Could you add your TYPO3 version? Since v9 EXT:seo is part of the Core and most extensions (like EXT:news) configure it for you out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hello. 
Am using Typo3 9.5.24. 
So you are saying there is little benefit to using cs_seo?

Comment: I am not aware of the cs_seo features but EXT:seo provides the most important backend fields and out-of-the box canonical and hreflang. It has an API for PageTitle and other meta tags. I have not used any other solutions since TYPO3 v9